# How to add Date and Integer in jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, date, salesforce, visualforce

Hi all,

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function duedatecal(){
            var invoicedate = $(".invoicedate").val();
             var paymentterms = $(".paymentterms").html();

          }
        </script>
        <apex:form>
        Date:
         <Apex:inputtext value="{!dateIn}" id="time" styleclass="invoicedate" onblur="duedatecal();"/> //say suppose date is 06/03/2013
        Payment Days:
           <apex:outputtext value="{!payment.Net__c}" styleclass="paymentterms"  /> //say suppose will get 10 days here
        Due date:
           <apex:outputtext value="{!duedate}" styleclass="duedate"/> // output shld be 16/03/2013
        </apex:form>
```

Whenever I change the inputtext(of Date) the duedate should be displayed accordingly by adding Date+payment Days.Help on this pls

Comment: i'm getting errors for what i have tried.I'm new to jQueries. Any Example for this pls

Comment: @EagerinSf is your payment box is an input field or not?

Comment: @GauravVashishtha no it is an output Field

Comment: @EagerinSf I have added a answer check that. it will be useful to you sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function duedatecal(){
    var dmy = $(".invoicedate").val().split("/");        
    var invoicedate = new Date(
                   parseInt(dmy[2], 10),
                   parseInt(dmy[0], 10) - 1,
                   parseInt(dmy[1], 10)
                 );

    var paymentterms = $(".paymentterms").text();
    var dueDate = new Date();
    dueDate.setDate(invoicedate.getDate()+parseInt(paymentterms));
    var duedates = dueDate.getDate()+"/"+(dueDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dueDate.getFullYear();

    $(".duedate").html(duedates);
}
```

Comment: Getting error as `TypeError: dueDate.format is not a function`

Comment: @EagerinSf I have modified the answer now use it. it will work.

Comment: in invoicedate.getDate() Im getting the value of MONTH where I need to get the value of DATE.My date format is like mm/dd/yyyy. so how can I get the value of date & add paymentterms to date but not to month

Comment: @EagerinSf I have changed the index of date now check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you could:

```
function duedatecal(){
    var invoicedate = new Date($(".invoicedate").val());
    var paymentterms = $(".paymentterms").html().val();
    var dueDate = new Date();
    dueDate.setDate(invoicedate.getDate()+paymentterms);
    return dueDate;
}
```

Comment: it is showing the wrong date.don't know how its adding but here is the alert message getting displayed for `invoicedate Sat May 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and `dueDate Tue Apr 14 2020 18:45:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`....:(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  It makes working with date and times in JavaScript much easier.

```
function duedatecal(){

    // parse the input date using a format string
    var invDate = moment($(".invoicedate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');

    // get an integer for the days of payment terms
    var terms = parseInt($(".paymentterms").text());

    // use moment.add with the days parameter
    var dueDate = invDate.add('days', terms);

    // output the due date, specifying a format string
    $(".duedate").text(dueDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
}
```

This assumes you are hard-coding the format for both parsing input and formatting output.  For other options, see the [moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: getting error as `ReferenceError: moment is not defined
var invDate = moment($(".invoicedate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');`